# How to reduce bundle size of Nuxt 3 website?

Tags: vuejs3, bundle, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

We have just put our new Nuxt 3 website online and we were shocked by the bundle-size of the entry file (307 KB). Also google is punishing us on our LCP which is too high. Is there a way to reduce the files without losing SSR? A link to an article or something would be great. We can't find anything but the standard image optimizing stories.

Comment: There is surely some way yes. Please give more details as to what you're using. You can give a try to [that one](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/commands/analyze#nuxi-analyze) or any kind of [bundle size vizualizer](https://github.com/btd/rollup-plugin-visualizer).

Answer (score 0):

If your entry file doesn't have much dynamic content, you can try Nuxt Server Components. Daniel Roe has an introductory guide here: https://roe.dev/blog/nuxt-server-components

Comment: Very scoped use-case of optimization but a viable one indeed.